# Phpstorm Git file colors

Tags: git, phpstorm

My PhpStorm is coloring changed files when Project is under Git . Where can I change color? Dark blue is not good readable.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to change color for file names in tab row of PhpStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489282/where-to-change-color-for-file-names-in-tab-row-of-phpstorm)

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open as, IMHO, the suggested target should be closed as the duplicate and this should be the target.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

File status colors can be changed at **Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | File Status**

**UPDATE:** Since 2018.x it moved to **Settings/Preferences | Version Control | File Status Colors**

Comment: Don't forget to go through all the properties selected and uncheck Foreground to get clear names of the files... Awsome @LazyOne

Comment: your comment should be added to answer!

Answer (score 2):

To be more specific: change these three colors under `File Status`

```
[option] Have changed descendants
[option] Have immediate changed children
[option] Modified
```

Comment: Phpstorm was once a good tool, now it simply got overcomplicated. i am using it since about 7 years now. I hope someone will programm a new ide for PHP. I would like to change font colors of files i modified but it simply does not work intuitively. Very sad