# Where to change color for file names in tab row of PhpStorm?

Tags: configuration, phpstorm

I am using the dark Darcula theme and git integration. Changed files are shown in a rather dark blue and new files are shown in a green which do not harmonize at all with the background color.

[image: Tab row of php storm with bad color scheme]

I am trying to change the color but cannot find the place in the options.

How to change the colors?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/14581202/457268

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phpstorm Git file colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581202/phpstorm-git-file-colors)

Comment: @ChrisMaes While technically a duplicate, I would mark the other one as a duplicate of this one (even though the other one is older) since the question is more readable and these answers here contain screenshots and are also more easily digestable. It would IMO e a disservice to have others be redirected to that other question.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can edit the colors of the file names under:

Settings > IDE Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > File Status.

[image: File status interface]

Comment: I had to apply/ok, then restart to see the change.

Comment: Would be awesome if the UI displayed the color next to the name, for an at-a-glance, you can easily find the color you want to change.

Answer (score 10):

It has moved in the newer versions (I am using 10.0.3) - they removed IDE Settings

Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > File Status > "Modified"

Note:I had to shutdown phpstorm and re-open for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

Was looking for this today. In the current version of PhpStorm 2020.03. It's in `File->Settings->Version Control->File Status Colors`. See below.

[image]