# Colouring new, modified, deleted etc. file names within PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

For some reason PhpStorm won't apply right colours to new, updated, deleted etc. files, neither in the navigation list nor in the tabs. I'm using GIT, PhpStorm 8.0.3 and OSX. As you can see below, all the file names are in white colour although the most of them are new and modified.

I already went through [Where to change color for file names in tab row of PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489282/where-to-change-color-for-file-names-in-tab-row-of-phpstorm), [Phpstorm Git file colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581202/phpstorm-git-file-colors), [File Colors](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/file-colors.html) and [File Status Highlights](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/file-status-highlights.html) so does anyone know what else I should do to activate file name colouring?

**EDITOR with new, edited, deleted files.**
[image]

**File before edit**
[image]

**File after edit**
[image]

**VCS 1**
[image]

**VCS 2**
[image]

**GIT status**

```
inanzzz-MBP:sport inanzzz$ git status
On branch form-type-crud
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   src/Football/FrontendBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: That;s the right place. Maybe you do not have any VCS integration setup?

Comment: I can confirm that It is set to GIT. Tested in same settings page and it said "GIT tested successfully".

Comment: 1) Could you please modify some small file: add few new lines/edit few existing and post a screenshot of it? 2) Screenshot of "Preferences | Version Control` please

Comment: @LazyOne - Added them, inc GIT status to show that the file is edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VCS1 screenshot indicates that Git integration is not correctly set for the project. Use the <kbd>+</kbd> button on the VCS integration window to tell PhpStorm where the root is.

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Aaaaa. That's it! I cannot believe I didn't notice that. Anyway, thank you for that. +1