# PhpStorm blue color of directories after changing file inside

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I change any file in PhpStorm all parent directories in Project View become with blue colors. It`s really annoying and difficult for reading. I tried different themes, schemes etc. but the problem still exists. I also removed "File Status" color and it works but only for files - not for folders...

Comment: And ... the question is?

Comment: Is your project under Git?

Comment: How to remove the blue color font of folders? :)

Comment: Yes andi, it was but I removed the whole git for the project.May be I have to try to clone it again..

Comment: maybe phpstorm still knows about the local repo. i haven't used phpstorm in a while, but i think the second answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581202/phpstorm-git-file-colors) fits your needs

Comment: Yeah, i made it but it works only for files - not for folders :(

Comment: Do you have `Settings | Version Control --> Show directories with changed descendants` option enabled? If yes -- please disable it. Otherwise -- maybe some custom plugin does that? Screenshot might help a bit as well (in case if it's not VCS status color)

Comment: I removed everything related with git as in the project as the whole ide. So it seems good, thanks @LazyOne and andi !